# Sql Query - How to Query multiple columns LIKE %keyword% and return to own arrays

Tags: php, sql

I need to query multiple different columns to retrieve their id to use for a future query. This works but if there are same ids it causes crossover with filtering. So I need to split the SELECT parts into separate variables. Can this be done without duplicating the code several times?
This is used in a live search so I don't want to query the table several times if possible.

Query

```
$Alltags = array();
$allTagsId = '';
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM mixes_radio WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' UNION SELECT id FROM mixes_category WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' UNION  SELECT id FROM mixes_mood WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' UNION  SELECT id FROM mixes_theme WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' UNION  SELECT id FROM mixes_instrument WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' ");

while ($row = $db->get_row($query)) {

    $allTags[] = $row['id'];
}
if (is_array($allTags)) {
    $allTagsId = implode(', ', $allTags);
} else {
    $allTagsId = 0;
}
```

This is one of the later queries I use the above returned ids for. $this->allTagsId is the returned from the above. You see I use it to further check a term in the column

```
 $songs = song_query("mixes_songs.trackName LIKE '%$this->term%' OR mixes_songs.mood_id IN ('$this->allTagsId') OR mixes_songs.category_id IN ('$this->allTagsId') OR mixes_songs.instrument_id IN ('$this->allTagsId') OR mixes_songs.theme_id IN ('$this->allTagsId') OR mixes_artists.artistName LIKE '%$this->term%'", $this->start, $this->end);
```

Comment: Do you want to get only one time each ids even if they appears multiple times in the query result ? If that is what you want, you should use SELECT DISTINCT id FROM...

Comment: @Titi two columns may have the same id tho and thats where it causes the issue. I will post the query I use this with.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome could you give a minimal example? not sure I understand

Comment: Actually I just read it again and I'm not sure that was good advice now I realise what you're looking for, sorry

Comment: @imposterSyndrome Just need to seperate the Selects out into seperate variable to use later. So $Select1, $select2 - I really don't want to query multiple times, I am sure there must be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, if I understand you answers, you need to separate your query result in multiple colums.

You can give an alias for each subquery and then get result of each subquery in a separate colum of your final result.

```
SELECT 
    mr.ids 'mixes_radio_ids', 
    mc.ids 'mixes_category_ids',
    mm.ids 'mixes_mood_ids',
    mt.ids 'mixes_theme_ids',
    mi.ids 'mixes_instrument_ids'
FROM (
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `id` SEPARATOR ',' ) 'ids' FROM mixes_radio WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%') as mr,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `id` SEPARATOR ',' ) 'ids' FROM mixes_category WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%') as mc,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `id` SEPARATOR ',' ) 'ids' FROM mixes_mood WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%' ) as mm,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `id` SEPARATOR ',' ) 'ids' FROM mixes_theme WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%') as mt,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `id` SEPARATOR ',' ) 'ids' FROM mixes_instrument WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR alt_name LIKE '%$term%') as mi
)
```

The result will be an array with $row['mixes_radio_ids'] containing the ids list for mixes_radio, $row['mixes_category_ids'] containing the ids list for mixes_category... etc

**UPDATE**

Explanation :

`GROUP_CONCAT( id SEPARATOR ',' )` is useful to group every values in one line, and separate them by the character that we want (here it's a coma).
And we give this value a name `'ids'` as if it was a real column.

Then we add an alias on each subquery `as mr`

And finaly, we encapsulate every subqueries in one query, and we can use each subquery result by calling its alias and the virtual column that we created `mr.ids`. And one more time, we can give a column name on each value, like `'mixes_radio_ids'`.

Comment: I can't quite grasp that query, but I tried it and it returned ```Unknown column 'mr.id' in 'field list'```

Comment: @Pop Sorry it's not easy because I can't test it in live =) I forgot a detail, can you try the update one please ? (I edited my answer)

Comment: Ok yes I understand it now, far above any queries I have done before!

Comment: @Pop Glad it works ! Just added an explanation if it can help you !